# pzc has a smaller size than mathcal

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize

I'm trying to use the `pzc` font for the symbol `E`, because I did not like the standard mathcal version. However, when I use it by defining it as:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}
```

Then `\mathpzc{E}`, while it produces the symbol I want, it's of a definitely smaller size than the standard mathcal one. Is there a way to make it larger?

[image: mathcal{A}, mathpzc{E}, mathcal{E}]

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prepared the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$\mathcal{A}$} \the\ht0

\sbox0{$\mathpzc{E}$} \the\ht0

\end{document}
```

(actually using `\showthe` to read the values on the console, here you read them in the PDF file).

Next I fired off a calculator and found that the ”A” is 110% of the “E”.

Then I looked in `ot1pzc.fd` to find

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{ <-> pzcmi7t }{}
```

OK, we want to load the same font, but magnified by 10%. We'd need

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{ <-> s*[1.1] pzcmi7t }{}
```

but it turns out it's too small, because the “E” has a loose bounding box. Final decision, use 1.2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{ <-> s*[1.2] pzcmi7t }{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{A}\mathpzc{E}\mathcal{F}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for nice lecture on how to work with it.